# Next Js - Full Calendar include CSS

Tags: fullcalendar, next.js

I am trying to use fullCalendar library(https://fullcalendar.io/) to display an event based calendar. When I run the code, I get the following error.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
> :root {
|   --fc-daygrid-event-dot-width: 8px;
| }
```

Below is my next-config.js

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const path = require('path');
const { assetPrefix } = require('./site-config');
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '@fullcalendar'
]);

dotenv.config();

const nextConfig = {
  assetPrefix,
  // exportTrailingSlash: true is required to ensure all files reside in the /assetPrefix folder
  exportTrailingSlash: false,
  env: {
    BRANCH: process.env.BRANCH,
    
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    config.plugins = config.plugins || [];

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    config.node = {
      fs: 'empty',
    };

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,

      // Read the .env file
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
        systemvars: true,
      }),
    ];
   

    return config;
  },
};

const sassOptions = {
  sassLoaderOptions: {
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
  },
};

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
// console.log('Building this path map:', pathMap);

module.exports = withPlugins([[withSass, sassOptions], [optimizedImages], [withFonts]], nextConfig),withTM();
```

I have also included the css files in _app.jsx like this,

```
import '@fullcalendar/common/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
```

What am I missing? Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance